# GASでループをする際に　構文エラー: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**やりたいこと**
GASを使用してGSSからdiscordの複数のチャンネルにメッセージを送りたいと考えています。
ループを使ってうまいこと送信できればと思ったのですが、エラーになってしまいました。
おかしいところがあったら教えていただきたいです。

```
function submit(){
  discord(get_value())
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx',0);
  //日付

  var datecoord = sheet.getRange(2,3);
  var date = datecoord.getValue();
  //format
  var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(3, 3);
  var format = formatcoord.getValue();

  //配信時間
  for (let i = 11; i <= 14; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
  
    var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
  
    return message;
  }
  
};

//googleスプレットシート  自動送信
function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};

//googleスプレットシート　ライバーdiscord情報
function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyyyyyyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyy',0);
    for (int j = 4; j <= 7; j++) {
      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,7);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,8);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();

  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,6);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();

    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = message;
      const username   = 'Spidey Bot';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true

      };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    }
    
}
```

**エラー内容**
discord関数のループの始まりである　for (int j = 4; j <= 7; j++)　が
43行目です。

```
構文エラー: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 行: 43 ファイル: コード.gs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for (int j = 4; j <= 7; j++)

`int`ではなく`let`では？

Comment: エラーは治り無事実行できました。　しかし、送りたいデータが全員同じになってしまっています。get_value()関数のところの配信時間について書かれている場所でループでセルをずらしていければ変わると思ったのですが、うまく変化がありません。何か原因があるのでしょうか？@Itagaki Fumihiko

Comment: get_sheet2って使われていないようですけど、関係ないですか？

Comment: すみません。そちらの方修正しても結果は変わりませんでした。@Itagaki Fumihiko